# Prove if ${\lim_{n\to\infty}}f(n) = L$‎, then ${\lim_{x\to\infty}}f(x) = L‎$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, monotone-functions

Let ‎$‎f:‎\mathbb{R}‎‎‎\rightarrow‎‎\mathbb{R}‎‎‎$ ‎be a‎ ‎monotone ‎function ‎such ‎that ‎‎$‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}f(n) = L‎$‎. Then, $‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}f(x) = L‎$‎.‎

‎
I know that if $‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}f(x) = L‎$, then $‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}f(n) = L‎$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$.  Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=L$, there exists $M$ such that if $n>M$ and $n$ is an integer, then $|f(n)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Now let $x$ be (a real number) greater than $M$.  Suppose $f$ is monotonic increasing (the decreasing case is similar).  Then $f(x)\ge f(M)$.  Suppose $f(x)>L$.  Then as $f$ is increasing,
$$f(\lceil x\rceil)>L$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)>L\ ,$$
that is, $L>L$, a contradiction.  Hence $f(x)\le L$.  We have shown that
$$f(M)\le f(x)\le L$$
and so
$$|f(x)-L|=L-f(x)\le L-f(M)=|f(M)-L|<\varepsilon\ .$$
We have shown that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $M$ such that if $x>M$ then $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.  By definition, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$.